# Scrolling pages in Ant Design tables

Tags: reactjs, scroll, antd

I have a table from ANTD and it has many pages, since I have defined pagination for it,
I want it to be possible to scroll as well, and go to the next page when the user scrolls to the bottom of the table.

this is my component:

```
 <Table columns={columns} dataSource={filteredData}
                title={() => <>  <h3>title</h3>}
                rowClassName="rowClassName"
                pagination={{
                    onChange: cancel,
                }}
            />
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Go to the next page when the user scrolls to the bottom of the table? What did you try?

Comment: Yes, do you have an idea? I'd love to hear it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the scrollable container `.ant-table-body` reaches the bottom, if the scrollbar reaches the bottom, go to the next page. After the pagination changes, scroll the scrollable container to the top.

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { Table } from 'antd';
import type { TableColumnsType } from 'antd';

interface DataType {
  key: React.Key;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}

const columns: TableColumnsType<DataType> = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    width: 150,
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    width: 150,
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
  },
];

const data: DataType[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    key: i,
    name: `Edward King ${i}`,
    age: 32,
    address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`,
  });
}

function calculatePage(pageSize: number, total: number) {
  return Math.floor((total - 1) / pageSize) + 1;
}

const allPage = calculatePage(10, data.length);

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({ current: 1, pageSize: 10 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const $tableBody = document.querySelector('.ant-table-body');
    const onScroll = () => {
      if (
        Math.abs(
          $tableBody.scrollHeight -
            $tableBody.scrollTop -
            $tableBody.clientHeight
        ) < 1
      ) {
        console.log('reach bottom');
        if (pagination.current < allPage) {
          setPagination((pre) => ({ ...pre, current: pre.current + 1 }));
        }
      }
    };
    if ($tableBody) {
      $tableBody.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      if ($tableBody) {
        $tableBody.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
      }
    };
  }, [pagination]);

  // scroll to top when pagination changes
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const $tableBody = document.querySelector('.ant-table-body');
    if ($tableBody) {
      $tableBody.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  }, [pagination]);

  return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={data}
      total={data.length}
      pagination={pagination}
      onChange={(pagination) => {
        setPagination(pagination);
      }}
      scroll={{ y: 240 }}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zgnmib?file=demo.tsx)